# Creating and Changing Default Directory for Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureportal

I've worked with a friend on an Azure project before, and now my default directory is set to their directory for some reason (I was invited to it). How do I create a new default directory in the Azure portal? I can't seem to figure it out and when I make new subscriptions, it adds it to my friend's directory.

Answer (score 1):

It's a by design behavior, the new subscription also belong to this default directory.
[image]

You can create a new Azure active directory, then use this directory to deploy your service.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: It ended up being an issue of me having to create a new active directory, set it as default, and move the subscription over to it. It's not super clear how to do this, especially since I was more familiar with the old portal, but it ended up working.

Comment: @muttley91 Do you mean you have create a new active directory in Azure, and set it to default?

Comment: Yeah that's what I had to do. It's more an issue of it not being super intuitive at that point.

Comment: @muttley91 As far as I know, we can't change the default active directory of the `Tenantid`. your subscription belong to this Tenant ID. Could you tell me why are you want to change the default active directory? maybe we need not to change it.

Comment: @muttley91 Please let me know if you would like more help.